# How can I generate a list of continuous names for a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to generate a list that is as follows:

1a 2a 3a 4a 5a

for use in a pandas dataframe, so far I've tried using:

df.set_index, & df.index.astype(str)

but this produces two dataframes one with each name
e.g

```
 1a 2a 3a 4a

1
2
3
4
  1  2  3  4
1b
2b
3b
4b
```

as opposed to

```
  1a 2a 3a 4a
1b
2b
3b
4b
```

Comment: transpose? `df2 = df1.T`

Comment: `[f'{i+1}a' for i in range(5)]` to generate the list

Answer (score 0):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({1: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                   2: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                   3: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                   4: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                   5: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

print(df)

   1  2  3  4  5
0  5  5  5  5  1
1  6  6  6  6  2
2  7  7  7  7  3
3  8  8  8  8  4
4  9  9  9  9  5
```

If your dataframe column headers is number 1 to 5 like above, you can use `rename` method:

```py
df.rename(columns=lambda x: str(x)+'a', inplace=True)
```

If not, you can replace the whole column header with `set_axis` method.

```py
df.set_axis([f'{i+1}a' for i in range(5)], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Both methods will give output

```
   1a  2a  3a  4a  5a
0   5   5   5   5   1
1   6   6   6   6   2
2   7   7   7   7   3
3   8   8   8   8   4
4   9   9   9   9   5
```